# kohana how to bundle javascript into view

Tags: javascript, view, kohana, bundle

I have a javascript with a counter, and a view.
I want the javascript counter to start whenever some one hits the buy product button.

my problem is: how can i control the javascript from the kohana controller, and how can i bundle the javascript into a view?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle the JS into the view just like into a typical .php page.

If page causes a post-back just start the JS timer on page load as usual.

If page uses AJAX, place JS into the content view. Then have a controller send a message that triggers the JS timer to count down.

Otherwise I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.